# Python Scrapy Click on html button

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and using scrapy with python 2.7 for web automation. I want to click on a html button on a website which opens a login form. My problem is that I just want to click on a button and trasfer control to new page. I have read all similar questions but none found satisfactory because they all contain direct login or using selenium.

Below is HTML Code for button and I want to visit `http://example.com/login` where there is login page.

```
<div class="pull-left">
    <a href="http://example.com/login" class="emplink">Employers</a>
```

I have written code for to extract link. But how to visit that link and carry out next process. Below is My code.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pro'
    url =  "http://login-page.com/"


def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(self.url, self.parse_login)


def parse_login(self, response):
    employers = response.css("div.pull-left a::attr(href)").extract_first()
    print employers
```

Do I need to use "yield" Everytime and callback to new fuction for just visiting a link or there is other way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to yield a new request or easier make a `response.follow` like in the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests):

```
def parse_login(self, response):
    next_page = response.css("div.pull-left a::attr(href)").extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.next_page_parse)
```

About the callback, it depends basically on how easily can the page gets parsed, for example, check the [general spiders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#generic-spiders) section on the docs